# Android Emulator became slow

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-mac

I was working with Android Emulator in Visual Studio for Mac with Xamarin. It was quite fast and everything was working fine. But once I closed it before it completely loaded, and now it does not boot, staying frozen on the black screen with Android word on it.
Can somebody please tell me what could have changed when I closed it and where I can fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't forget to check the obvious: Your AVD settings. Check the "Advanced Settings on Android studio -> Network" to make sure that it is not set to emulate poor connectivity. 
Then go to the "..." menu in the emulator and check "Settings -> Proxy". Also go to "... -> Cellular" and check that here, too, network is set to "Full", "Great signal strength".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem once. 
It turn out that the settings was lost.

Tap on your emulator in the top left console.

[Then Manage google emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj5WW.png)

[Choose ur emulator > Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvQsG.png) And return initial settings.
Hope that helps

If it does not work u can try to make new emulator.